# How to remove entire directory from RootDirectory in ZIP extension

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, zip, build-process, tfsbuild

I have a build that needs to zip a website project. I am using `TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.Compression.Zip` to do this.

Unfortunately, it puts the deployed files into `..\_PublishedWebsites\ProjectName\`.
So, I have tried to play around with the RemoveRoot property, in the ZIP extension.

If I use the following value:
`(New DirectoryInfo(BinariesDirectory & "\_PublishedWebsites")).FullName` my zip file contains the ProjectName folder and it then contains the website. Working as intended.

If I use the following value:
`(New DirectoryInfo(BinariesDirectory & "\_PublishedWebsites")).GetDirectories().FirstOrDefault().FullName` my zip file contains the ENTIRE folder structure, from `C:\Builds\..`. This is definitely not what I expected.

All I want, is that instead of having a folder in my zip, I want the deployed files directly in the zip files root.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Web Deploy**](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy) should be your first choice for packaging web sites.
[It has a built-in option for zipping the artifacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323) so you don't need any third-party libraries for this.

Comment: I don't want it deployed to any IIS though. It looks like the standard build templates also deploy websites in the solution, but to the build folder.

Comment: Web Deploy allows publishing to a zip file without affecting any web sites. It was designed for developer workstations that doesn't have access to the target web servers.